# How to parse file input in java?

Tags: java

I was wondering how else it would be possible to parse the information from a file.  I only want to grab 2 values from each line and each line is made up of about 5 different items.  I've figured out how to do it in the most basic sense but this wouldn't hold if the data was changed slightly. Is there a way to skip certain values without doing this way?

Here is how the data looks that is being read. I only want the first two values per line to be able to compare them against other values that are user entered.

> 3  Joshua  25,965  Hannah  18,802
>
> 14     David          39,915   Helda   18,811

Here is my current method but I would like to figure out a better way maybe using a pattern matching function but I am unsure of how to do that.

```
while(readFile.hasNext(){  
            if(gender == 'M'){      
                rank = readFile.nextInt();      
                compareName = readFile.next();      
                skip = readFile.nextInt();      
                garbageName = readFile.next();
                skip = readFile.nextInt();  
}
```

Comment: Use `nextLine`, the either use a different `Scanner` to parse the line or split on the `,` delimnator

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the input line by line, using the nextLine method and then parse each line individually (either using a Scanner or String.split() or other method).

```
while(readFile.hasNext(){  
    String line = readFile.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
}
```

If the file contains

14 David 39,915 Helda 18,811

, in tokens[0], you will have the string "14", in tokens[1], "David" and so on.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example if possible, I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: String.split() will split integers and commas as well?

Comment: For example if I wanted to check if a name entered was an actual name/string and not a set of numbers like 000. How would I be able to check that? I think the term I'm looking for is regex?

Comment: Yes, if you want to make sure the line has a specific format, you should use a regex

Comment: I'm going to give that a shot right now.
Would tokens[1].equals(name) still work?

Comment: I'm trying 

    found = (tokens[1].equals(name)) ? true : false; 
And it doesn't seem to be finding the names in the file. I think because the tokens are split by more then one white space character and sometimes tabs even.

Comment: My tokens[1] is storing \tJacob\t30,541
How would I fix that?

Comment: Firstly, that's not necessary. found = tokens[1].equals(name) is more readable and has the same result. You need to add \t to the split parameter: String[] tokens = line.split("\t ");

Comment: Some lines of data are separated with tabs others with spaces. How would I set the split delimiter to match either one of those?

Comment: Add both characters in the string you pass as argument to the split method, as I did in  my comment above.

Comment: I tried the code you provided in the comment and now my tokens variable looks like this tokens[0] =  1 \tJacob\t30,541 \tEmily \t24,450
No other indexes in the tokens array.

Comment: I am sorry, my bad. Use line.split("\\s+"); to ignore all whitespaces